# Go through excel sheet and display information on html

Tags: java, html, excel, japplet

My task is to create a simple html that will take all the information from an excel sheet and display it into a html page. Not really that important for now but in the future, make the change live. So if the excel document gets updated, the html page gets updated almost instantaneously. I will basically just need to open the html page and I can see all the data from the excel sheet.

What I'm thinking of doing is using some java code, and then embedding that in the html to display it.

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/

That seems like something I could mostly reuse for the java portion. I don't know if there are better options to do this. Are there any other ways you could suggest where I can accomplish my goal but would be simpler or more efficient?

In the future, how could I possibly make the change on the html page live or close to live if the excel sheet changes?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Jasper report. 
It can read from excel : see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025127/jasper-report-with-excel-data-source). 
and it can output to html ; see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405173/send-jasperreport-as-html).